# Does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin(1/n)}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin(1/n)}$ converge?

I thought about Dirichlet's test, I know that $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\ge\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)} $ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}=0$, but how I can continue?

Comment: Note that certain special functions (like $\sin$ and $\ln$) have their own commands. For instance type `\sin` in stead of `sin`. Same for $\ln$. Also `\geq` is the command for the $\geq$ sympbol (and `\leq` gives $\leq$).

Answer (score 3):

It diverges trivially:
$$\frac1{\ln n}\cdot\frac1{\sin\cfrac1n}\sim_\infty\frac1{\ln n}\cdot\frac1{\cfrac1n}=\frac n{\ln n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}+\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sin(1/n) \le 1/n.\,\,\,$